# The Microsoft jet database engine could not find object while reading dbf file

Tags: c#, oledb, dbf

I am facing very strange issue. I have written class to which reads dbf file through `oledb` connection. I have downloaded dbf file from internet and it is reading all data correctly.

*DBF file location: E:\Projects\SLAVE.DBF*

I am facing following 2 issues

1) When I try to read other dbf file then it is reading only its table fields. it is not reading table fields data.
`E:\Projects\line75.dbf`

2) The other issue I am facing I have DBF files when I put these files in location then i am getting exception that

> microsoft jet database engine does not find required object. Are you
>   missing some directive or path. `E:\Projects\SDW_plnParcel.dbf`

I am totally confused why it is reading `SLAVE.DBF` downloaded from internet correct, why it is not reading TABLE FIELDS DATA of `line75.dbf` and why it is  throwing exception on `SDW_plnParcel.dbf.`

My class and one function for this class is as follows:

```
public class dbfHandler
{
    public dbfHandler()
    {
        this.dbfTable = new DataTable();
    }
    public void initconnection(String filepath) // initialise dbconnection
    {
        String[] splitString = filepath.Split('\\');
        this.filename = splitString[splitString.Length - 1];
        splitString = splitString.Where(w => w != splitString[splitString.Length - 1]).ToArray();
        String folderPath = String.Join("\\", splitString);
        this.dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + folderPath + ";Extended Properties=dBase III");
        this.dbConnection.Open();
    }
    public List<String> getcolumnvalues(int fieldIndex, List<int> rowIndexes)
    {
        List<String> columnvalues = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            if(this.dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                string mySQL = "select * from " + this.filename;  // dbf table name
                OleDbCommand MyQuery = new OleDbCommand(mySQL, this.dbConnection);
                OleDbDataReader reader = MyQuery.ExecuteReader();
                int rowCount = 0;
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    bool match = rowIndexes.Any(item => item == rowCount);
                    if(match == true)
                    {
                        String value = reader.GetValue(fieldIndex).ToString();
                        columnvalues.Add(value);
                    }
                    rowCount++;
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        return columnvalues;
    }
    private String filename;
    private DataTable dbfTable;
    private OleDbConnection dbConnection;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with .DBF files, I have always had better results working with [Microsoft's Visual Foxpro OleDb Provider](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14839)

The connection string in simplified format

```
var connString = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\SomePathToData;";
```

Now, instead of doing the data reader -- just to make sure you can get / see what you are expecting, try using a DataAdapter...

```
var da = new OleDataAdapter( yourSqlCmdObject, yourConnection)
var dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

It should pull all columns from your query and all rows into proper data column types... Then you could cycle through all the column names, rows, etc..

```
foreach( DataColumn dc in dt.Columns )
   var tmp = dc.ColumnName;

foreach( DataRow dr in dt.Rows )
{
   object x = dr[0];   // get VALUE from column 0
   x = dr["SpecificColumn"];   // if you KNOW the column name
}
```

Of which, you could tweak as needed.  But if you only need a SPECIFIC column (or limited columns), change your query to quantify that.

```
Select OneField from YourTable...
```

Comment: sir i am getitng error DBF is not a table. I have used the almost same code as aboce. it is reading some DBF file but in most cases it is giving error that DBF is not table

Comment: @MuneemHabib, is it possible that the dbf file you are attempting to use has been encrypted by a 3rd party utility?  Such as Cryptor?  If so, the native OleDb won't recognize it

Comment: @MuneemHabib - I get this message when opening a table with more than 255 fields/columns. I've been googling this but I can't seem to fix this without pulling a rabbit out of my a... hat!

Comment: @RobbieVercammen, DBF tables have a limit of 255 columns.  If your table has more than that, then I suspect a different database provider, such as SyBase Advantage Database Server or SyBase Advantage Local Server which can read / work with DBF files, but has its own database container to handle larger than standard DBF context.